# 3D estimation of tennis courts using opencv

Tags: java, opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to do camera calibration and 3D estimation of tennis court from a single image. At first as preprocessing I do canny edge detection and then apply hoare transform to get the lines. From this I clean the image to get the court edges. [image: sample image after hoare transform]. From this I am trying to estimate the 3D pose of the court (may be after camera calibration). The methods for camera calibration in opencv seem to be for pre existing patterns. As I know the court dimensions is there any method to get the 3D parameters from a single image? Or can we calculate the corresponding matrix from parallel lines more easily?

Comment: I think this should be doable. Given enough point correspondences 2D <-> 3D, you should be able to retrieve the intrinsic and extrinsic matrices.

Comment: with known court pattern it should be easy to calibrate. using parallel lines afaik you need at least 2 or 3 vanishing points (different line directions) but in that image you 'll only get one vanishing point since the horizontal lines are quite parallel to the image plane.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at it...

Step 1: I clicked on "known" world points in the camera image that you'd basically already found. I ran `ginput` in MATLAB and clicked on 14 point intersections that should be derivable from your Hough lines. Here are those points, in units of pixels (you can draw them overtop of the original image to see where they are):

```
x = [
   161   118
   193   119
   382   116
   412   116
   181   149
   288   147
   393   146
   134   268
   287   266
   440   266
    36   358
    98   358
   473   352
   535   353
   ]';
```

Step 2: I calculated the corresponding world points, treating the top left of the court as origin (0,0,0) and increasing down and to the right. Every point has a Z-coordinate equal to 0 since the court is a plane. Here are those points, in units of feet:

```
y = [
   0 0 0
   4.5 0 0
   31.5 0 0
   36 0 0
   4.5 18 0
   18 18 0
   31.5 18 0
   4.5 60 0
   18 60 0
   31.5 60 0
   0 78 0
   4.5 78 0
   31.5 78 0
   36 78 0
]';
```

Step 3: We now have a bunch of correspondences between camera points and world points. I used the camera calibration toolbox to derive the extrinsic and intrinsic parameters of the camera. Note that since we have so few correspondences, I skipped the calculation of the distortion parameters and aspect ratio (which should be very close to 1.0 anyway). The resulting image here shows the original world points mapped to the image given *only the calibration information*. We can see that the calibration was effective, in that all world points are mapped very closely to their correct locations in the image.

Here's the final code:

```
clc;
clear all;

img = imread('HSY1A.jpg');
nx = size(img,2);
ny = size(img,1);

% imshow(img,[]);

x = [
   161   118
   193   119
   382   116
   412   116
   181   149
   288   147
   393   146
   134   268
   287   266
   440   266
    36   358
    98   358
   473   352
   535   353
   ]';

y = [
   0 0 0
   4.5 0 0
   31.5 0 0
   36 0 0
   4.5 18 0
   18 18 0
   31.5 18 0
   4.5 60 0
   18 60 0
   31.5 60 0
   0 78 0
   4.5 78 0
   31.5 78 0
   36 78 0
]';

num_pts = size(y,2);

% Required by camera calibration toolbox
x_1 = x;
X_1 = y;

% Setting up calibration parameters
n_ima = 1;
est_aspect_ratio = 0;
est_dist = zeros(5,1);
% check_cond = 0;

% Run calibration
go_calib_optim;

%% Estimate original points
est_x_1 = KK * [Rc_1 Tc_1] * [X_1; ones(1, size(X_1,2))];
est_x_1 = est_x_1 ./ repmat(est_x_1(3,:),3,1);

%% Plot results
imshow(img,[]); hold on;
plot(est_x_1(1,:),est_x_1(2,:),'gs');
```

And here's the resulting image:

[image]

Comment: @aardvark is there a tutorial for this in Python without using Matlab?

Comment: @mLstudent33 Not that I know of -- I believe I just made it up.

Comment: @aardvark, I know the height of the center strap of the net, net posts and using OpenPose on the players, can approximate their heights and the height of the ball at impact on various shots.  Is this enough to create a 3D model where I could track the trajectory including ball bounce points?  Here is a "demo" of what I have so far:  https://youtu.be/QctKFhOkqKg